# Does OMNet++ support Power6?

Tags: omnet++

I am optimizing MAC parameters with Evolutionary Computation. So I need to call OMNeT++ run a network simulation more than 1000 times. Does OMNet++ support Power6 to get results faster?

Answer (score 1):

OMNeT++ runs under Linux and needs little more than a working C++ compiler. As far as I know, the GCC compilers support this processor, so I don't see why it shouldn't work.